# Imbalanced training data columns in regression training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, cross-validation, hyperparameter

I have a training data which after cleaning, wrangling has around 17k with more than 40 columns. The categorical columns are 35 and numerical 5. The categorical columns have value either 0 or 1. Now the thing is this training set is highly imbalanced as for every column I have, it has roughly 90% of the column as 0 and 10% like 1. I'm trying to predict prices using these columns. As I try to predict values using these columns  I get a training score of 80% and validation of around 43-44 %. I have used Random Forest, XGBoost regressors for prediction. I have also tried cross-validation, hyperparameter tuning for these but the results don't seem to improve. Is it that the data is not right - being highly imbalanced and all or is it a problem with the model . How do I improve this crappy model ?

P.S : I can't share the data or code due to company policy

Comment: What metric are you useing? If you are getting that great a disparity between your training and test sets then it is likely an issue of over-fitting. Without seeing your exact code it is hard to say for certain, but some harsher cut-offs for hyper-parameter might be in order to avoid overfitting. How are you concocting your data partitions currently?

Comment: I'm using RMSE and R2 as my metric. I'm using K-fold cross validation where k=3/5/10 as my partitions. This was to prevent overfitting but sadly didn't work

Comment: Just to clarify, your test set is then randomly selected from the data? Have you tried increasing the range of the hyper-parameters? You could also try support vector regression. Lastly, there is always the potential that your covariates (a.k.a. features, inputs, etc.) are not up to the task (i.e. they aren't capable of predicting price accurately).

Comment: Yes , it is randomly selected from the data . I printed out the indices each time.

Comment: Covariates are not up to the task ....how do I figure that out?

Comment: By trying all the other avenues as we have outlined here. If the models are still reporting poor test accuracy after you have tried the full suite of models, hyper-parameter ranges and a robust sampling strategy then it is likely that the predictors are inadequate for predicting the price. One more thing you might try though is randomly splitting your data with the condition that each split has proportionate representation of  the full spread of your "price data". In other words, when you create your folds they are representative of the distribution of prices you see.